# Do PSone Classics have trophies?

Tags: achievements, ps3, psone-classics

I'm seriously considering getting the PSOne Classics edition of *Final Fantasy Origins*, but I'm just wondering: Do PSOne Classics releases have trophies?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this website](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/playstation-nation-1000002/ps1-classics-do-they-have-trophies-26917681/) it appears that they do not have trophies linked to them.  [This Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vita/comments/4xfxy6/do_ps1_classics_have_trophies_or_online/) compliments the other website as well.  This is likely because the original games did not have trophies and going back to add trophies was not an option.